# Saved exr looks different than in rendered image inside of blender

Tags: rendering

I took the alpha channel in account and render in exr. But the window seems to be clipping out a lot of colour except for at the corners and the mist plane is fully disappearing. I would like to try more things but the image outside of blender is exactly what i want. It is just when i save it or render animation that it messes up and misses things in the image. Any ideas are welcome! First is the saved image and the second one the rendered image inside of blender.

Edit: I should also mention that it occurs in exr as well as png file format.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. openEXR uses linear color space,in order to get sRGB or anything different, you need to convert to the correct color space,  the way of doing that can be different depending on the software (AE, DaVinci Resolve, etc). You just need to search for your particular software

Comment: But the changes i'm seeing in my saved files aren't just changes in colour but whole parts of the render (the mist for example) missing.

Comment: Blender shows a checker so that you can better see semi-transparent things, your EXR viewer didn't. Alpha isn't necessarily treated the same way too.

Comment: @L0Lock so what can i do to make it visible when im using the rendered files in after effects.

Comment: @Emir i've gotten to a stage in AE where i can now see all the detail that was in the file but i've lost the transparency of it. I cant seem to fix that by interpreting it differently either.

Comment: I don't think that there's any easy way to save the effects on transparency, there are some tedious tricks though